# How to use the platform bom from spring.io with gradle in subprojects

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-boot

I would like to use the bill of materials from the platform with gradle in all my subprojects.
http://platform.spring.io/platform/

The documentation describes how to activate the bom in single project.
The use of the spring-boot plugin is required. We will use the spring-boot plugin, but only in  a single subproject. 
The other projects should only profit from the bom but will not contain a "main" class for spring-boot to run.

Run gradle in the root folder:
gradle build
....

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':subproject:bootRepackage'.

> Unable to find main class

I did not find any examples on the internet. 
How can I share the bom with my subprojects and still use spring boot actively?

Thanks!

**Update**:
I found the answer

In the build.gradle of the parent project:

subprojects{
...
bootRepackage.enabled = false;
bootRun.enabled = false;
...
}

And subsequently in the build.gradle of the subproject needing spring-boot:

bootRepackage.enabled = false;
bootRun.enabled = false;

Now gradle builds correctly.
Moreover, in the root folder the following command delegates the bootRun to the correct submodule:
gradle bootRun

Answer (score 1):

Use `io.spring.dependency-management`

Nice feature is that [you can use Spring's dependency plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#managing-dependencies-using-in-isolation) even if you're not interested in Spring Boot.

*build.gradle.kts*:

```
plugins {
    id("io.spring.dependency-management").version("1.0.6.RELEASE")
}

subprojects {
    apply<DependencyManagementPlugin>()

    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            mavenBom("com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bom:1.11.409") // Import any bom!
        }
    }
}
```

Now in subproject:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb")
}
```

So you've only applied `io.spring.dependency-management`, not the whole Spring Boot plugin and there is no need to disable Spring Boot (which looks like a hack).

Answer (score -1):

Using the Spring IO Platform BOM doesn't require you to use Spring Boot.  The BOM does indeed compliment using Spring Boot, but it's main purpose is to provide a curated set of dependencies that work well together in your Spring project.  Using it in your dependency management also means you don't need to specify the version of the dependency you want if the BOM already provides it.

Using Spring Boot allows you to create a "microservice" style web application, but in no means is it a requirement to use the Spring BOM.  If you need to use the Spring Boot plugin in only a single module, then you should only add it to that module.

Comment: Quote from: http://docs.spring.io/platform/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/
" The Platform uses Spring Boot’s Gradle plugin to provide dependency versions in your build. The use of a plugin is necessary as Gradle does not provide an equivalent of Maven’s built-in dependency management support. Note that using Spring Boot’s Gradle plugin to provide version management doesn’t require you to use Spring Boot to write your application."
--  
This states you cannot use the bom without forcing spring-boot on the submodules

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize this difference between Gradle and Maven.  I usually stick to Maven myself.